# How to retrieve state of recyclerview in a fragment from a bundle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an activity `HomeActivity` where I navigate between two fragments `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`. The `Fragment1` fragment contains a recyclerview. When I move to `Fragment2`, `Fragment1` is paused and stopped. When I come back to `Fragment1`, the list loads again. How to return to the scroll position from which I left? One way which I have tried is to save the state of recyclerview in a bundle before the fragment is paused in `onPause()` method. Now, how do I use this save state when view is created?

The navigation code is:

```
final NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_controller);
binding.go_to_fragment2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                navController.navigate(R.id.fragment2);
            }
        });

        binding.go_to_fragment1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                navController.navigate(R.id.fragment1);
            }
        });
```

The code for `Fragment1` is:

```
public class Friends extends Fragment1 {


    private FriendsFragmentBinding binding;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private static Bundle RecyclerState;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {




            binding = FriendsFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
            binding.mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
            binding.mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

            PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                    .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                    .setPageSize(5)
                    .build();

            // Init Adapter Configuration
            Query mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("posts");
             FirestorePagingOptions<Post> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Post>()
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .setQuery(mQuery, config, Post.class)
                    .build();
            binding.swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    myAdapter.refresh();
                }
            });

            myAdapter = new MyAdapter(options, new MyAdapter.GetState() {
                @Override
                public void thisState(boolean state) {
                    if (state) {
                        binding.swipe.setRefreshing(true);
                    } else {
                        binding.swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }
            });


            binding.mRecycler.setAdapter(myAdapter);
            return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Parcelable listState = Objects.requireNonNull(binding.mRecycler.getLayoutManager()).onSaveInstanceState();
        RecyclerState = new Bundle();
        RecyclerState.putParcelable("key", listState);
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `binding.mRecycler.setAdapter(myAdapter);` before your adapter has any data set. It is when your adapter is set that the saved scroll position is restored. Since there's no items in your adapter, there's nothing to scroll back to, so your scroll position is lost.

As per the [Restore RecyclerView scroll position blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334), you have two options:

1. Don't set your adapter until you get data for the first time.
2. Upgrade to [RecyclerView `1.2.0-alpha02`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#recyclerview-1.2.0-alpha02) or higher and switch the [`StateRestorationPolicy`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy) to [`PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy#PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY):

`adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY`

Which will mean that the `RecyclerView` will wait until your adapter is populated with data before restoring its state, thereby restoring your scroll position correctly.

Comment: I have this `rv.adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY` and it shows a lint error: `Smart cast to 'MAdapter' is impossible because 'rv.adapter' is a complex expression`. May I cast it manually with no issue?! (I'm getting the adapter from `rv` as the adapter doesn't have the `stateRestorationPolicy` method itself!; It's a `PagedListAdapter`)